# Where to place my .sdf file when testing application through Emulator

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, smartphone

I am work on smartApplication, Here when am trying to connect to my SQL Server CE 2005 database, I get the exception

**The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\SmartProject\DBFile.sdf ]**

My connection string is

**Data Source=D:\SmartProject\DBFile.sdf;Password=test123**

and the code to connect is like

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=D:\\SmartProject\\DBFile.sdf;Password=test123";
    SqlCeConnection Connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand(SqlSelectCommandText, Connection);
    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(comm);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
        else
            dataTable = new DataTable();
        bsuccessfullyExecuted = true;
    }
    catch (SqlCeException ex)
    {
        bsuccessfullyExecuted = false;
        dataTable = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }
```

when the code try to open the connection it throw this exception provided the file is at the specified location or directory.

It works when I just place the DBFile.sdf file with the .exe in bin and remove the path except the Database file name from connectionstring.

but when I try to access it through Emulator it show this error. provided that its connect through cradle and Windows Mobile Device center.
It show all the page but when I try to access the Db it through exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we have to put `DBFile.sdf` in Mobile Device Folder and now connection string would be

```
Data Source=\Temp\DBFile.sdf;Password=test123
```

this Temp is in the Mobile Device folder as our designer session connected to a SQL Mobile database which is on a mobile device connected through ActiveSync.

As a result, the connection string to the database which is automatically generated with the bindingsource is a special connection string that only works from within VS2005 and it begins with DataSource = Mobile Device.....

So for Emulator we have to put sdf file in Mobile Devide and as above